# Import SCSS files from parent directory on Heroku Cedar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, sass

I'm trying to deploy a Rails 3.1 app I was working on locally. But once deployed to Heroku (Cedar stack), I encounter an issue I wasn't having locally, and I can't find any solution to this.

Actually, in some of my SCSS files, I import other SCSS files located in the parent directory. Among the several syntaxes I tried :

```
 @import "file.css.scss";
 @import "file";
 @import "/file.css.scss";
 @import "/file";
 @import "../file.css.scss";
 @import "../file";
```

Most of these work locally, but none work on my heroku Cedar app. I also tried renaming my imported file into "_file.css.scss" with an underscore, as it seems it's the standard format for SCSS files made to be imported. But didn't change anything.

The error heroku logs are giving me is :
`ActionView::Template::Error (File to import not found or unreadable: /mixins.css.scss.`

I'm getting out of ideas right now, so would be thankful if you had any clues to solve this.

Thanks a lot,
Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

The syntax should be

With the following folder structure

```
/app/
  /assets/
    /stylesheets/
      /pages/
       index.css.scss
       products.css.scss
      application.css.scss
```

If you wanted to include the scss files in /pages/ from application.css.scss you would do this:

```
@import "pages/index";
@import "pages/products";
```

You should also be able to do the following (however I'm not sure if this is limited to having Compass in the project or not).

```
@import "pages/*";
```

Being able to do glob imports is awesome. But I think it may be Compass only, or at least it used to be.

Answer (score 0):

If the file your importing is within the same folder the following should work:

```
@import './file.css.scss';
```

I found it's important to have the relative path and file extension present when I ran into a similar issue.  Since you were trying to use ../ that would look for the file your importing in the parent folder rather than within the same folder.

Answer (score -1):

Your best bet is to use the built in Rails Asset Pipeline to handle including your style files.

In your `app/assets/stylesheets` folder you should have a file named `application.css`. This file uses [Sprockets](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets) to automatically include all of your css files placed inside of the `app/assets/stylesheets` folder.

At the top of the file you'll see this:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll automatically include all the stylesheets available in this directory
 * and any sub-directories. You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at
 * the top of the compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree . 
*/
```

The `*= require_self` part includes any css style written in this actual `application.css` file, while the `*= require_tree .` part includes assets found in `app/assets/stylesheets`.

If you'd like to change the order of inclusion, or specify a specific stylesheet, for example a file named `mixins.css.scss` located in `app/assets/stylesheets`, here is how you'd do that:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll automatically include all the stylesheets available in this directory
 * and any sub-directories. You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at
 * the top of the compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree . 
 *= require_mixins
*/
```

And the magic of sprockets will include your file for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I didn't even think of this. But actually, looks like using require and the asset pipeline will cause me trouble as I have mixins and variables in the files I want to import, and they do not appear at compilation time when using the Assets Pipeline. Therefore, I can't use my variables and mixins in the "calling" file (getting a "undefined mixin" error for instance). Some more details here : http://dev.af83.com/2011/06/14/2-require-tips-for-rails-3-1-assets-bundling-with-sprockets.html

Comment: Have you tried requiring your Mixins at the top of each file in your asset pipeline setup?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I tried. And I got the "undefined mixin" error.